# Choppy cursor when keys pressed

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I'm having a problem with cursor movement on my laptop.  Whenever I hold down a key and move my USB mouse simultaneously, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFRgBjKdUBM) happens.
Normally this wouldn't be much of an issue, but unfortunately it makes most video games unplayable.
The behavior occurs with both built-in keyboard and USB keyboard, but does not occur with the trackpad.  I have tried using a different mouse but the behavior stayed the same.
I am currently running Ubuntu 15.04 on a MacBook Pro.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The output from `lshw -c video`:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:a0000000-a03fffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:2000(size=64)
```

Comment: What graphics chip (brand/model) and which driver for it do you use? Best [edit] your question, adding the output of `sudo lshw -c video`.

Comment: @the_Seppi my video card is "Intel® Ivybridge Mobile"

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `mouseemu` package solved the issue.